# Return json list of values in SQL Server 2016 using data from 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a database with 2 columns

```
A     B
--    --
X     1995
Y     2005
C     1962
D     2003
```

I'm trying to create a SQL statement that will take a string of comma delimited values and return a json list of values in B where any value in the string is in A

so if the comma delimited string was `'X,C'` the json list would be `[1995,1962]`

I've been using json path to try this, but I can't get it exactly like I want it and I've been spinning my wheels for too long

This is what I've tried:

```
Select mt.B as json_list_b_values
 From  [dbo].[myTable] mt
Where  mt.A in (Select value From String_Split('X,C', ',')) for json path
```

This is the ouput:

```
[ {"json_list_b_values":"1995"}, {"json_list_b_values":"1962"} ]
```

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: How does what you're getting not match your desired output?

Comment: Can you provide your output based on the sample data provided ? that will be helpful

Comment: @Avi i added it to the post. is it not showing up or is there something else you'd like to see? i'm not sure

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza json_list_b_values":"1995" I did not understand this part..How did json_list_b_values this come ?

Comment: @Avi that's the output from the SQL statement. I don't know what to tell you. i'm replacing information in my post to protect sensitive data i'm working with so maybe i made an error in hiding the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're on 2016 you can't use `STRING_AGG`, but you *can* use the old tried and tested `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` method:

```
DECLARE @list varchar(8000) = 'X,C';
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM(VALUES('X',1995),
               ('Y',2005),
               ('C',1962),
               ('D',2003)) V(A,B))
SELECT '[' + STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',V.B)
                    FROM VTE V
                         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@list,',') SS
                    WHERE SS.[value] = V.A
                    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']';
```

Answer (score -1):

I am no SQL expert. So please bear with me.

**Step 1 - Handle the CSV input**

You are already doing this by using the **IN** clause.  I would store these results in a table variable

**Step 2 - Convert the query results to a simple JSON array**

I can think of the function **STRING_AGG()**. This will concatenate the rows into a flat string.

E.g. Join the FirstName column into a comma delimited string

```
SELECT STRING_AGG ( ISNULL(FirstName,'N/A'), ',') AS csv 
FROM Person.Person;
```

Will produce the following

```
John,N/A,Mike,Peter,N/A,N/A,Alice,Bob
```

**Code snippet based on your example**

I am using a table variable *@result1* to hold the result from **Step 1**.

```
SELECT '[ "' + string_agg( json_list_b_values, '", "') + '" ]' FROM @result1
```

**MSDN reference for STRING_AGG()**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**CORRECTION**

The function *STRING_AGG()* is available in SQL 2017.